# Is groupby from pandas commutative?

Tags: python, pandas, commutativity

I would like to know if the rows selected by:

```
groupby(['a', 'b'])
```

are the same as the rows selected by:

```
groupby(['b', 'a'])
```

In this case the order of the rows doesn't matter.

Is there any case in which `groupby` does not fulfill the commutative property?

Comment: in term of number or result, they are same, but for understanding the data , a-b a is group and b is subgroup , it also show in the index , which make the data table more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think order for counts not matter, only after groupby get first columns/ levels in order like you have columns in list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a':list('aaaaaa'),
         'b':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'c':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})
```

Order of levels after `groupby` aggregation:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).sum()
print (df1)
      c
a b    
a 4  19
  5  14

df2 = df.groupby(['b', 'a']).sum()
print (df2)
      c
b a    
4 a  19
5 a  14
```

And columns:

```
df3 = df.groupby(['a', 'b'], as_index=False).sum()
print (df3)
   a  b   c
0  a  4  19
1  a  5  14

df4 = df.groupby(['b', 'a'], as_index=False).sum()
print (df4)
   b  a   c
0  4  a  19
1  5  a  14
```

If use transormation for new column with same size like original result is same:

```
df['new1'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].transform('sum')
df['new2'] = df.groupby(['b', 'a'])['c'].transform('sum')
print (df)
   a  b  c  new1  new2
0  a  4  7    19    19
1  a  5  8    14    14
2  a  4  9    19    19
3  a  5  4    14    14
4  a  5  2    14    14
5  a  4  3    19    19
```

Answer (score 8):

Per [definition](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) and the logic applied when using `groupby` in `pandas`, it will always be commutative:

> A groupby operation involves some combination of splitting the object, applying a function, and combining the results.

This combination is linear hence commutative. The importance, is that when passing multiple `by` values, there will be an order in the new index values that should be kept in mind when addressing them.

From wikipedia's [linear combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) and [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property):

> In mathematics, a linear combination is an expression constructed from a set of terms by multiplying each term by a constant and adding the results.
>   The idea that simple operations, such as the multiplication and addition of numbers, are commutative was for many years implicitly assumed.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, the final groups will always be the same.

Only difference is the order in which rows will be showed.